# How to exclude a dependent jars pom.xml from it's called place

Tags: docker, spring-boot, maven-2, maven-3, microservices

I have a situation, where I have a project A which has reference to project B.

Project A is using a different jar version of spring-boot (i.e.., 2.6) while B is using a different version (i.e.., 1.3.3), and because B is added as dependency for A, the execution is failed due to jar conflict. Can anyone advise me how to exclude all the jars that pertain to B? Only selective exclusion is the way or any other way to exclude all the jars.

Answer (score 0):

You can include `project A` as a reference to `Project B` but exclude its dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.company</groupId>
    <artifactId>projecta</artifactId>
    <version>your.version.here</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>dependency-you-want-to-exclude</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Comment: But I will need to do one by one right? Ex: if there are other set of jars then I need to cherry pick one by one, and insert manually?

Comment: Yes, you will need to explicity exclude whatever you want to exclude.